# How to use validation_messages and display_exceptions in Apigility?

Tags: error-handling, exception, zend-framework2, laminas-api-tools

From the Apigility documentation ([Error Reporting](https://apigility.org/documentation/api-primer/error-reporting)):

> The API Problem specification allows you to compose any other additional fields that you feel would help further clarify the problem and why it occurred. Apigility uses this fact to provide more information in several ways:
>
> - Validation error messages are reported via a `validation_messages` key.
> - When the `display_exceptions` view configuration setting is enabled, stack traces are included via `trace` and `exception_stack` properties.

I don't understand this part of the docu. What is the **purpose** and **how to use** the settings `validation_messages` and `display_exceptions`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `display_exceptions` setting is from ZF2's view manager ([see docs here](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.view.quick-start.html?highlight=display_exceptions#configuration)).  Turning this on will cause Apigiltiy to include a stack trace with any error response.

In Apigility itself the `validation_messages` key population is handled automatically.  You configure an input filter which validates the incoming data payload and if the input filter fails the error messages it returns are automatically injected into the API response under the `validation_messages` key.  This functionality is provided by the module [`zf-content-validation`](https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-content-validation).  You can "do it yourself" by returning an  `ApiProblemResponse` from your resource like so:

```
return new ApiProblemResponse(
    new ApiProblem(422, 'Failed Validation', null, null, array(
        'validation_messages' => [ /* array of messages */ ]
    ))
);
```